# One way data binding not working when using date pipe

Tags: date, angular, data-binding, ionic2

I'm using a date object to keep track of the current date in an application.

In my view I have a one way binding like this:

```
<h3>{{ currentDate | date }}</h3>
```

And in the component, I have functions to change this date, like this:

```
previousMonth(){
   this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() - 1);
}

nextMonth(){
   this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

But when these functions are triggered, the `currentDate` value doesn't update on the view.

I made sure the date object is being updated, just not on the view.

Whenever I remove the date pipe, it works.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is not updating in the view because the pipes in angular are so called *pure* (or, stateless) by default. That means that the input will not be re-evaluated if the input object changes, but only if it's replaced.

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) (see section *Pure and Impure pipes*):

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the
>   input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input
>   value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference
>   (Date, Array, Function, Object).

Try the following code instead:

```
previousMonth(){
   this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() - 1);
   this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate);
}

nextMonth(){
   this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
   this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate);
}
```